# What is the relationship between hypergeometric, negative binomial and poisson?

Tags: probability

You have 100 flavors of jelly beans. There's one jelly bean of every flavor, and a sixth of the flavors are edible while the rest are inedible.

As the experiment gets "larger", the Poisson, negative binomial, and hypergeometric solutions tend to the same numerical answer.**

This is the part that I am stuck on. I know that hypergeometric should converge to binomial but I don't understand why the question is saying that Poisson, negative binomial and hypergeometric should converge to the same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A strange question.  If the number of flavours is the only parameter that changes, the $1/6$, $2$, $8$ and $10$ staying the same, then it's patently false to say that the solutions all tend to yield the same numerical answer (there is a complication that the fraction can't be exactly $1/6$ unless the number of flavours is a multiple of $6$, but I'll disregard that).

The probability of getting $2$ inedible beans in $10$ draws (with replacement) is always going to be $5$ times the probability of getting the second inedible bean on the $10$'th draw, under the same circumstances, because the former includes
45 equally likely outcomes (where an outcome tells which draws were inedible and which were edible) and the latter only 9 of those.

Comment: ah I see. so would it be correct to say that the poisson, binomial and hypergeometric tend to yield the same numerical answer? –

Comment: The binomial probabilities for a population of size $N$ of which a fraction $p$ are edible don't depend on $N$.  The hypergeometric appoach the binomial as $N \to \infty$.  The binomial approximates the Poisson in a different way: the number of beans drawn must go to $\infty$ with the edible fraction going to $0$ in such a way that their product, which is the expected number of edible beans drawn, stays constant.

Comment: ah thank you. also isn't it true that binomial approaches poisson only if $p <<1$?

Comment: because the variance of the binomial is $np(1-p)$ and the mean is $np$. if $p<<1$ then the variance is $np$ which is the same as teh mean. for the poisson the mean and variance are both $\lambda$ so if $p<<1$ we can approximate binomial with a poisson with $\lambda =np$

Comment: but in this problem $p<<1$ is not the case